# Problems with titlesec for non-TOC subsections

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec

I want to format both sections and subsections with a leading `\S` (section) symbol, but don't want subsections to appear in the TOC, so I wrote

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\S\ \thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\S\ \thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection A}
\end{document}
```

This worked properly for the section, but the subsection got no leading symbol. The output was

[image]

If I remove the `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}`, everything works as expected (except of course for the TOC entries). I assume there's some way to tell titlesec what I want, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the counter `tocdepth`, not `secnumdepth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\S\ \thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\S\ \thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @rogerl You would not be the only one needing coffee.  I knew packages like `tocloft` had a toc depth mechanism, but only stumbled across the fact that it is built into LaTeX directly.