# Titlesec: Need to make format exception for Contents and References

Tags: titlesec

I am using titlesec to place the \S character the begining of each section and subsection title.  It is also appearing on the title of the table of contents, and also the title of the references section.  How can I make an exception for these two sections?

---

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter\S}{\thesection}{1em}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large\bfseries\filcenter\S}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{TOIC}{}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Answer is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371633/31034

Comment: @ferahfeza Thank you